# Paying aliments: how to consider debt from divorce itself?

Tags: germany, divorce

It seems I may be divorced in Germany and I want to get my calculations right.

I have a house worth 150k€. I have paid 50k€ before marriage. I have paid 100k€ during marriage. Remaining debt is exactly 0€. The goods acquired during marriage is 100k€. So I have to pay my wife 50k€. To do so, I need a credit from the bank.

Now it comes to aliments and I use [this calculator (Unterhaltsrechner)](https://www.smart-rechner.de/unterhalt/rechner.php). Say we both earn 2500€ and share 2 kids of age 10 equally.

Since I live in my own house, I don't pay rent. This will be considered as an advantage for me. Let's say 500€.

My question now is: since I have to pay back the 50k€ by some monthly fee (444 € as an example), can I consider that amount as outstanding debt or not?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried figuring that out with websearch. I found references for debt which remains from before divorce (can be considered). I also found references for debt after divorce (cannot be considered). However, this debt occurs exactly with the divorce, same second.